# Firefox css animations

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations

I have mobile view animation which works perfectly on Chrome mobile but on Firefox the element positioning result is way off. Works fine in Opera and Safari.

```
<div 
class="fptext">text/text   
Text/text</div>
<div  
class="fatext">text/text/
text/txt</div>
```

CSS-ANIMATION:

```
@media (max-width: 768px). 
{.fptext {animation: fadeout 
50s ease forwards;animation. 
delay: 0s;padding:0px;
}}

@keyframes fadeout{
from {font-size: 0px} to 
{font-size: 40px;}}

@media(max-width: 768px). 
{.fatext{animation: bigger 
50s ease forwards;animation. 
delay: 0s;; 
position:relative;font-size: 
15px; color:#43ff0a;bottom: 
1700px; font- 
weight:bolder;padding: 
0px;background 
color:blue;display:block
;margin-bottom: -1750px
}} 

@keyframes bigger 
{from{font-size: 0px} to 
{font-size: 18px;}}
```

See mobile [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Comment: I guess your mobile is android based right ?

Comment: Yep.............

Comment: But it works fine on apple mobile with safari

Comment: "Result is way off" is not a technical description of the problem.

Comment: The CSS Validator flags lines 5 and 22 as parse errors.

Comment: Which css validator?

Answer (score 0):

i inspected your code on my browser and when i have cross browser issues i start with a normalize or reset depending on my needs, i didnt see either in the head when i inspected so you may see an improvement by just adding a normalize.css to your project. also you are worrying about a problem for 0.62% of the united states market share, so less than 1 percent of people use it.

Comment: Thanks. Would I put that in my theme `header.php` or in `<head>normalize.css</head>`on individual page?

Comment: if you are bringing the head dynamically with php then put this <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/normalize.css"> in there or put it in your head as long as its loaded to the page, and then just make your normalize.css and copy it from https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css